# Add new fields and Hide unwanted fileds in Custom Module in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm new to openerp.I want to add new fields to inherited custom module and at the same time i want to remove unwanted fields in newly created Custom Module.I want add some details like Mothername and Fathername and also i want to hide unwanted details like job position and website.Can any one please tell me.
Thanks in advance

My Code :

**init**.py

```
import lead
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
'name': 'Lead Information',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """This module is Lead information.""",
'author': 'Nitesh',
'website': '',
'depends': ['base'],
'init_xml': ['lead_view.xml'],
'update_xml': [],
'demo_xml': [],
'installable': True,
'active': True,
'application': True
}
```

lead.py

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class cus(osv.osv):
 _name = "lead.partner"
 _inherit = "res.partner"
 _description = "This table is for keeping lead data"
 _columns = {
    'mothername': fields.char('Mother Name',size=10,required=True)
   }
```

lead_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ===================== This is tree layout =============================-->
<record id="lead_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="model">lead.partner</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="mothername"/> 
            <field name="website"  position="attributes"><!--removed / from the end-->
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="model">lead.partner</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="mothername"/>
            <field name="function"  position="attributes"><!--removed / from the end-->
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </field>

       </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================= Action Layout ============================= -->
    <record id="action_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="lead_tree"/>
    </record>
       <!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
    <menuitem name = "Lead" id = "menu_lis_lab" action="action_lead"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: If you define _name field <> _inherit field, a new object will be created. Therefore, you have to create a new view. I mean, you cannot inherit the existing view

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove any field than use this,

```
<field name="website"  position="replace"/>
```

you can remove fields which are from parent view. this is right way.

You can use these values in the position attribute:

- inside (default): your values will be appended inside the tag
- after: add the content after the tag
- before: add the content before the tag
- replace: replace the content of the tag.

for more details - http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_03.html
Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: and one more thing, if you are defining tree view and form view for model lead.partner then you must use this same model in act_window. so correct that it should be lead.partner instead of res.partner. and better give your view_id refernce as "lead_form" which is your form view

Comment: Thanks Mansi.It was very helpful. Can u please tell me who can i add new fields to my custom module if i inherit res.partner

Comment: you want to add fields in res.partner itself by inheriting it?
if so, then
class res_partner(osv.osv):
 _inherit = "res.partner"
 _description = "adding fields to res.partner"
 _columns = {
    'mothername': fields.char('Mother Name',size=10,required=True)
   }
res_patner()

Comment: i'm getting the following error " except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')"

Comment: you have to set res.partner in view also.your error will be solved

Comment: Thanks a ton Mansi.Thanks alot for helping me.I'll bug u with more doubts.Now it is working fine.Now i came to know my mistake,I'm trying to add new field "xyz" in xml and database both at the same time.Openerp is unable to find the field because it is not create it.SO first we need to add the fields in lead.py and upgrade and the add them in lead_view.xml and upgrade it will work fine.

Comment: If you dont mind can i get ur mail id.I want to add you in my Linked Network and bug you with all my doubts :-P

Comment: if i click link in your profile i'm getting this on Linked Webpage "You and this LinkedIn user don’t know anyone in common

You can only view the profiles of users within your network. However, as you add connections, you may discover people you know in common."

Answer (score 1):

First add create the fields in *.py file and upgrade your custom module and later add the fields in *.xml and upgrade the module again,it will work perfectly fine.Now i can add the fields and hide the unwanted fields in my custom module
ex:I want add Mothername and Father name below "JObPostion" and to hide website field
the below is the working code

My code

lead_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ===================== This is tree layout =============================-->
<record id="lead_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="lead">
                <field name = "name"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="view_res_partner_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.res.partner.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <field name="website" position="replace"/>
                <field name="function" position="after">
                    <field name="mothername"/>
                    <field name="fathername"/>
                </field>
            </data>    
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================= Action Layout ============================= -->
    <record id="action_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="lead_tree"/>
    </record>
       <!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
    <menuitem name = "Lead" id = "menu_lis_lab" action="action_lead"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

and

lead.py

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class res_partner(osv.osv):
 _inherit = "res.partner"
 _description = "adding fields to res.partner"
 _columns = { 
    'mothername': fields.char('Mother Name',size=64,required=True),
    'fathername': fields.char('Father Name',size=64,required=True)
 }
```